# how put my product->get_image in js

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

i need to put my $product->get_image in ajax but i don t know how to do

i want to put my $product->get_image(...) to $details = Array("..., "img"=>"$imgL");

here s my code

```
<?php 

define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);  
require_once('wp-load.php');
global $qode_options_theme16;
global $wp_query;

$sku=$_POST['id'];

        $args = array('post_type' => 'product','meta_value' => $sku);
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
            $i=0;
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product;



             $imgL=$product->get_image( $size = 'shop_large', $attr = array(), $placeholder = true );                  
             $prix = $product->get_price(); 
             $nom = $product->get_formatted_name();





            endwhile;


        } 

$details = Array("prix"=>"$prix", "nom"=>"$nom", "sku"=>"$sku", "img"=>"$imgL");
 echo json_encode($details);    

?>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Where is the code failing? It looks weird that you are getting the id but then querying array('post_type' => 'product','meta_value' => $sku) this? What meta_key are you querying against?

Comment: there is not fail in my code , i can recover my $product->get_image, but the problem it s at the moment where i ll recover my $imgL with ajax , it gives me just "/" or nothing

Comment: i thinks it's because that  $product->get_image() need several params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please call the code like this:

```
 $imgL=$product->get_image( 'shop_large', array(), true );
```